# Prove that $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_3$ are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$ without using that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, normed-spaces

Prove that $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_3$ are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$ without using the fact that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent.

In other words I need to show that there exist $m,M>0$ such that $$m\Vert x\Vert_3\le\Vert x\Vert_2\le M\Vert x\Vert_3$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
Where $$\Vert(x_1,\dots,x_n)\Vert_k= \sqrt[k]{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^k}$$

Attempt:
I tried using induction to prove that $\Vert x\Vert_2\ge\Vert x\Vert_3$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$ but it got really messy, so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Also i have no idea how to do the other inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\|y\|_2 \leq 1$ then  $\|y\|_3 \leq 1$ too because $|y_i| \leq 1$  and so $|y_i|^{3} \leq |y_i|^{2}$. Now take any non-zero $x$ and put $y=\frac x {\|x\|}$ to conclude that $\|x\|_3 \leq \|x\|_2 $. Thus we can take $m=1$.

Next note that $\|y\|_3 \leq 1$ then  $\|y\|_2 \leq 1=\sqrt n$ because $|y_i| \leq 1$ for  all $i$. Hence we can take $M=\sqrt n$.

Comment: I am sorry why does $|y_i|^3\le|y_i|^2$ prove that $\Vert y\Vert_3\le 1$?

Comment: @Nasal I am saying that $\sum |y_i|^{2} \leq 1$ implies $\sum |y_i|^{3} \leq 1$.

Comment: So, after introducing a normed vector $y,$ is this the order of conclusions for $m$ $\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|_2}\right\|_2=1\implies\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|_3=\frac{\|x\|_3}{\|x\|_2}\le 1\implies\|x\|_3\le\|x\|_2$ ?